# Change style for HTML and embedded XML in the same time

Tags: html, css, xml

I have some HTML5 files in which I embedded XML through **object** element. Now, for the HTML files I have alternate stylesheets. What I want to do is to change the style for the embedded XML (because the XML file has its own stylesheet) in the same time with the HTML. So, when I choose a style for the HTML page with the help of the browser, I want the style of the XML to be also changed. Is there any way to do this?

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>LondonDiamond Restaurant Menu</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" media="screen" title="Standard red black white"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style_print.css" media="print" title="Print"/>
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/alt_style.css" media="screen" title="Monochrome"/>
</head>
<body>
    <object data="../xml/menu.xml"><span></span></object>
</body>
</html>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="../css/style4xml.css"?>
<!DOCTYPE menu SYSTEM "../dtd/menu.dtd">

<menu>
     irrelevant
</menu>
```

What happens is that when I chose the alternate stylesheet for the HTML, the colors change, but the embedded XML keeps the same color (and it is normal) BUT I also want to change it in the same time with the HTML.

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to apply the same default and alternative stylesheets both for the HTML files and the XML ones. And in the CSS files I have the style for the HTML and XML elements.

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>LondonDiamond Restaurant Menu</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" media="screen" title="Red Black White"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style_print.css" media="print"/>
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/altstyle.css" media="screen" title="Monochrome"/>
</head>
.......
</html>
```

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" title="Red Black White"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="../css/altstyle.css" alternate="yes" title="Monochrome"?>
 <!DOCTYPE menu SYSTEM "../dtd/menu.dtd">

 <menu>
      .....
 </menu>
```

CSS:

```
body {...}
header {...}
...
menu {...}
```